# How to do form validation with JS for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Chrome content security policy says,

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both
>   inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. `<button onclick="...">`).

I wanted to validate the input with JS. Since onsubmit,onclick or anything cannot be used how can I do this? I am new to JS and extension development. Any help is entertained.

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers. Use `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `addEventListener`, e.g. something like this:

```
// Function to add event listener to table
var el = document.getElementById("targetElement");
el.addEventListener("click", function() { alert('Hoorey!'); }, false);
```

this goes on a separate .js file.

Comment: As I have said, I am fairly new to JS. It will be quite a lot helpful if u could share any tuts to understand the concept of `addEventListener`. I can try if its easily available in googling :)

Comment: Sure! That's standard JavaScript method for attaching event listeners to any DOM elements. That's really helpful source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution with jquery considering your want to make sure multiple inputs are valid and then let the user submit the form:

```
// selectors
var input1 = $(#input1ID); // name
var input2 = $(#input2ID); // phone

// regular expressions
var regexp_input1 = /^[a-zA-Z]$/; 
var regexp_input2 = /^([0-9]$/;

// map object
var your_form_map  = {
// map variables
 input1 : false, // if it is required 
 input2 : true // if it is not required but you dont want the user input incorrect characters. 
}

var invalid_color = "red";
var valid_color = "green";
function validForm (selector, regexp_variable, map_obj , map_var) {
    selector.on('change keyup anyotherevent addwithspace',function(){ // CHANGE validates input with auto complete which you can hardly disable it with chrome. 
        if (regexp_variable.test($(this).val()) == false || $(this).val().trim().length === 0) {
            $(this).css("color" : invalid_color);
            map_obj[map_var] = false;
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).css("color" : text_valid);
            map_obj[map_var] = true;
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

now lets call out validator function:

```
validForm(input1, regexp_input1, your_form_map, "input1"); // second input1 is your map's object variable NOT your input selector.
```

Time to submit your validated form:

```
$('your_submit_btn_ID').on('click anyOtherEvent', function() {
   var temp = true;
   for (var key in your_form_map) { // looping through your map object and make sure all inputs are true. 
       if (!your_form_map[key]) {
           alert(key + "is invalid");
           return false;
       }
   }
   // submit your form here ...
   $.ajax({...});
   // have fun here... 
});
```

Comment: I am not good with JQuery. Just began with JS now. In future I shall surely will keep a look into this. :) Thank you so much.